# Configuring IP-DLC Link TO AS400 issue

Tags: ibm-midrange, sna

I have created a IP-DLC link by following "Configuring IP-DLC Link Service for IBM Enterprise Extender White Paper" document
Please help me to resolve this error.

```
BIND(-RSP) request received in response to a BIND request
       Sense code         = 0x080f0001
       Local LU name      = APPN.HISPU       
       Partner LU name    = APPN.C101C31D    
       Mode name          = CPSVCMG 
       BIND RU : 

       31001307 b0b050b3 07879797 87070602
        00000000 00004014 2300000a c1d7d7d5
        4bc8c9e2 d7e42b00 0802c3d7 e2e5c3d4
        c7090301 234e5768 2dfca40b 04c1d7d7
        d54bc8c9 e2d7e40a 13006a16 1636341e
        093b000d c1d7d7d5 4bc3f1f0 f1c3f3f1
        c42c0904 07c3d7e2 e5c3d4c7 6013f923
        4e57682d fca40ac1 d7d7d54b c8c9e2d7
        e4 

     Cause:
      BIND(-RSP) received in response to a BIND request. This may indicate a configuration error, or a protocol error. 
      Common sense codes which typically indicate a configuration error or a normal race condition include 
       0805xxxx - the session could not be activated as session 
                  activation limits have been reached 
       08060014 - the partner LU is not known 
       0806xxxx - the BIND specified a resource which is not known 
       080Fxxxx - security authorization failed 
       0821xxxx - the BIND supplied an invalid session parameter 
       0835xxxx - parameter error in BIND RU at offset
      Other sense codes include 
       0812xxxx - session activation failed due to resource shortage 
                  at the remote node 
       083Bxxxx - invalid PCID in BIND RU 
       0852xxxx - duplicate session activation request 
       0861xxxx - invalid COS name in BIND RU 
       088Cxxxx - control vector or subfield missing from BIND RU 
       0895xxxx - BIND RU contained a control vector that was in 
                  error 
       0896xxxx - BIND RU contained a control vector that was too 
                  long

      Effect:
      Session activation will fail with the specified sense code.

      Action:
      If the sense code indicates a configuration error, check for inconsistencies between the configuration at the local LU and the configuration at the partner LU.  If the configuration is consistent and the problem persists, contact support with details of the problem.
```

Comment: your error is *Sense code = 0x080f0001* the message says *080Fxxxx - security authorization failed*. With whatever credentials you use, those credentials are not authorized. This is not something we can fix.

Comment: I am configuring HIS2010 and I have created IP-DLC link, During creation of link there is no setting where I can put any credentials. So I Believe this settings is in AS400 side. I hope some one with as400 knowledge can help me to fix this issue. Thank you for your reply anyway.